# Is learning English as a second language a skill or a knowledge?

Tags: english, l2-acquisition

I  think  learning English is  not  just learning a  skill like  other skills (for example carpentry) because  learning  is  also  knowledge  based, like  history  and  physics.

**Language  helps  us  to  think  creatively, laterally  and  helps  us  even  to  think abstractly. So  I think  teaching  English  is  not  just  teaching  and  improving  the  four  skills.**

My  question  is:

**is learning  a  second   language like English  a skill  or a knowledge**?

Comment: Carpentry is also knowledge based. It is not unskilled labour.

Comment: The act of learning is neither. It's a process.

Answer (score 1):

Learning (and remembering) is a skill itself, you can improve your learning skills (applied to anything, not only to a learning a language). It is just a different skill than carpentry, or swimming, or cooking.

Learning languages is a skill, subset of generic learning skill.

Knowledge is a *result* of applying that learning skill, like pie is a result of applying your cooking skill, or drawer is result of applying your carpentry skill.

Answer (score 1):

The human brain is the most complex thing in the known universe & using language is the most demanding thing we ever use it for. Whatever epistemology we choose, it's going to be extremely complex so there's never going to be a simple, straightforward answer to questions about what knowledge or skills are. Not in any useful way.

A common definition: Listening, speaking, reading, & writing are all examples of competencies. Competencies consist of combinations & configurations of knowledge, skills, & attitudes (KSAs). However, KSAs exist at different levels of analysis/complexity & exhibit dual structure, i.e. KSAs made out of KSAs, or KSAs nested within KSAs. It's complex!

Another common definition/distinction: Declarative knowledge is facts that you can talk about, describe, define, etc.. Procedural knowledge is knowing how to perform processes but not necessarily being able to talk about how you do them. Obviously, there isn't a clear dichotomy/dividing line between them. The declarative vs procedural distinction is sometimes useful for clarifying which learning & teaching strategies & techniques are more appropriate to a given learning objective. Again, it's complex!

A common claim in language learning is that words are knowledge & how we organise them into phrases, clauses, & sentences (syntax) is a mostly unconscious skill. This is a very narrow claim & cannot account for things like discourse, registers, & genres. Also, words exhibit syntactic features, just to muddy the waters further, e.g. "Tell me this." is correct but "Explain me this." isn't. Why? (Answer: See Adele Goldberg's work on construction grammar & usage-based models of language)

There's a variety of models of knowledge & language of which some are useful depending on what you're trying to do. An analogy is that models are like tools & you should have several tools in your tool box, e.g. hammer, screwdriver, & tape measure. Which one you choose depends on whether you're working with nails, screws, or lengths of wood.

A useful saying: "All models are wrong. Some are useful." - George Box (statistician)

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. E.g., from the point of view of applying for jobs, terms *skill* and *knowledge* mean rather different things.

English as a *skill* means that you can do your job in this language. E.g., your can speak to clients in English (rather than a local language), you may discuss the content of your work in English - e.g., when working with your colleagues from another country, etc.

English as *knowledge* means that your job has intrinsically to do with English - e.g., you are an English teacher or translator. This would typically require a higher level of mastery and likely having relevant professional certifications.

One could also mention intermediate situations: e.g., editing documents in English or teaching in English (e.g., teaching math) typically requires nearly perfect proficiency, although English here is still closer to being skill.